# Probability that the $9$th extraction is the first one for which $3$ white balls are extracted

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

We are given an urn with $9$ balls: $5$ black and $4$ white. We extract $3$ balls from this urn at each step, check their colors, then put them back in and repeat. What is the probability that the $9$th extraction is the first occurence where $3$ white balls are extracted?

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Do I need to use some more advanced probability theory? I have tried this, but it doesn't really feel right:

The probability of extracting $3$ white balls in the first extraction is $p=\frac{4}{84}$. So the probability of this **not** happening is $1-p$. So we have $(1-p)^9$ probability of this not happening $9$ times, so $1 - (1-p)^9~=0.355$ of this happening the $9$th time.

Where am I wrong, if I am? How should this be solved?

Comment: I guess $p=\frac{4}{84}$ ?

Comment: So we are to assume that none of the middle $7$ extractions have $3$ white balls ?

Comment: @lsp none of the first 8 must have 3 whites.

Comment: Check the solution posted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we need to get $3$ white balls for the first time in our $9$th extraction, none of the extractions from $1$ to $8$ should have all three white balls.

Probability = $(1-p)^8*p = (1-\frac{1}{21})^8*\frac{1}{21}=(\frac{20}{21})^8*\frac{1}{21}$